# SQL Server to PostgreSQL equivalent

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I need some help in converting or equivalent of below in postgreSQL..

From MSSQL code to postgreSQL:-

1. `CONVERT(bit,CASE WHEN column_a & 1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ABC`
2. `CONVERT(tinyint,CASE WHEN column_a IS NOT NULL THEN 0  END) as ABC`
3. `CONVERT(smallint,CASE WHEN col_year = (SELECT year(col_date)  FROM tab A WHERE A.a = 192) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ABC`
4. `TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(YEAR(Date))||'Y') as ABC`
5. `CASE WHEN COL_A = 1 THEN TO_CHAR(YEAR(Date))||'Y'`
6. `WHEN COL_A = 4 THEN TO_CHAR (YEAR(Date) ) || 'Q' || TO_CHAR(Month(Date)/3 ) ELSE NULL END as ABC`

Please help..

Comment: Please explain what each statement is doing. You can't assume that those that know Postgres also know SQL Server. But `TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(YEAR(Date))||'Y')` doesn't look at all like T-SQL

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sure..these are all conversion statements in sql to other data types based on case statements basis..just looking for equivalent postgres ones..replacements as there is no to_char(year) in postgres nor convert..thanks

Comment: Well "conversion into another SQL type" is done with `cast()` in Postgres.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks..yes cast im aware..however im mainly confused on TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(YEAR(Date))||'Y')...whats the equivalent on pg..

Comment: For one: there is no `to_char()` in SQL Server. And `TO_CHAR(TO_CHAR(YEAR(Date))||'Y')` makes no sense to begin with and SQL Sever doesn't use the standard `||`  concatenation operator - so that can't be your SQL Server code. But if `Date` is a column with the data type `date` then I guess(!) you might be looking for `to_char("date", 'YYYY"Y"')` in Postgres.

Comment: There is a `TO_CHAR()` function in Oracle. So please clarify if these queries/snippets are from Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  thanks very much...that helped a lot..just fixing this below from what you suggested...CONVERT(scovert (smallint,CASE WHEN colyear= (SELECT year(coldate) FROM table x1_0 WHERE x1_0.colDate1 = 100) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ABC, IN PG...                                                                                                                    
 It is like..anything wrong here.. cast(case extract(coldate) when x0_0.colyear) as SMALLINT FROM table x1_0 WHERE x1_0.colDate1 = 100) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ABC   ??

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ no its SQL..not oracle

Comment: SQL is a language not a DBMS product. If you mean SQL Server (the Microsoft DBMS) then you are simply wrong. It doesn't have any `TO_CHAR()` function and neither has a `||` operator. Your queries / snippets cannot possibly run in any version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what the `convert()` parts are supposed to do, but I am trying to guess(!) what the intention `to_char()` (that can't be valid SQL Server code) is trying to achieve.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) `to_char()` needs two arguments: the value to be formatted (e.g. a `date` or `timestamp` value) and the "format mask".

To extract the year as a string from a `date` (or `timestamp`) value and append the letter `Y` use:

```
to_char("date", 'YYYY"Y"')
```

e.g. `to_char(current_date, 'YYYY"Y"')` returns `'2021Y'`. Alternatively use `to_char("date", 'YYYY')||'Y'

[The format mask](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE) to get the quarter is `'Q'` and `'MM'` for the month. So to get a string with a date's quarter use `to_char("date", 'Q')`.

To extract the month as a number, use the [extract()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function, e.g. `extract(month from some_date) / 3`

To extract the year use `extract(year from some_date)`

---

`CONVERT(tinyint,CASE WHEN column_a IS NOT NULL THEN 0  END)` looks like you just want a flag if the column is null. This can be e.g. written as `column_a is null` which will return a `boolean` value with `true` or `false` (slightly different than you original expression that returned `null` if the column is `null`). If you really prefer numbers instead of `booleans` use `case when column_a is not null then 0 end`. I don't exactly know what that `convert()` function is doing, but you really don't like `booleans` or `integers` to be used as a flag, then maybe you want to cast that to a `smallint`: `cast(case when column_a is not null then 0 end as smallint)`

Comment: thanks very much...that helped a lot..just fixing this below from what you suggested...CONVERT(scovert (smallint,CASE WHEN colyear= (SELECT year(coldate) 
 FROM table x1_0 WHERE x1_0.colDate1 = 100) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ABC,                          IN PG...It is like..anything wrong here.. cast(case extract(coldate) when x0_0.colyear) as SMALLINT  
 FROM  table x1_0 WHERE x1_0.colDate1 = 100) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ABC,

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)  `extract()` needs **two** parameters and the `from` keyword is mandatory. So obviously `extract(coldate)` is wrong - it must be `extract(year from coldate)`. Please do read the manual - the correct syntax for all functions I mentioned is documented there including all allowed values for the parameters.

Comment: thanks again...sure..somehow this isnt working for me..let me check the manual...its going above my head currently..                                                               CAST(CASE extract(year from coldate)  When x0_0.colyear) as SMALLINT 
 FROM tbl.Cola x1_0 WHERE x1_0.colddate = 192) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as ABC,